# Storage Space Parity disk running very slow

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, storage-spaces

The problem started, or at least noticed after expanding the virtual disk to 5 TB during a network file transfer.

What happens is if I'm transferring a file to the server (running 2012 R2) it writes for a while then stops, then it starts transferring again, stops and the windows machine notifies that the file transfer timed out. works the same way when reading a file from the server as well.

Same thing happens when I access it remotely, I play a video file, first it buffers for a while plays the first few seconds and then starts buffering again...

I tried chkdisk It said it found no errors, I then move to Get-VirtualDisk
I see that the virtual disk health is at warning, I do Get-PhysicalDisk to make sure that the hard drives are healthy which they were and then I just ran the Virtual disk repair after which it seemed to change the health status from warning to healthy.

But the problem persists, anyone have experience with this problem?

I have Gigabit Ethernet running so I doubt that it's network issue but I will try to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your description i cannot tell for sure that's the reason for this behaviour.

Taking the unhealthy state in concern, one of your physical drives *may* have failed/nearly failed for some time and caused the virtual disk to get into this state.

Having disks to not really fail (fail fast is much better than die slowly) and just taking very long for seeks / write operations (but still not hitting the timeout) is quite hard to dig into.

**Checking for a unhealthy disk:**

In general, i recommend to check resource monitor for a peek (virtual disk queue lengths) view. If you're seeing queues on your virtual disks, check your physical disks. When you've located a corrupt disk, replace it (*removing would also improve performance if it's exactly one disk - but you'll lose resiliency if you don't use double parity*).

Comment: Thank you, I guess it took a slow death but now Server Manager is telling me the hard drive is detached, I will try replacing the SATA cable but otherwise I believe its dead. Also to anyone who might have this kind of issue I found crystaldiskinfo to be very helpful

Comment: how to find out which physical disk is corrupted? remove one by one?

Comment: There a several ways to find corrupt drives that may work depending on your environment. Best is to check response times / queues under load using performance monitor. If this doesn't work check reliability counters (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-storagereliabilitycounter?view=win10-ps).